# Which parts of the Reichstag building are open for tourists?

Tags: sightseeing, germany, berlin, government-buildings

I would like to visit the Reichstag building in Berlin, Germany and I wonder:

- Which parts of the building are open for tourists?
- Is it for free?
- Do I need a reservation?
- Are there any restrictions for non-German citizens?

Comment: admission is free and worth visiting.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is the official website where you can get all the informations you asked for (in english as well): http://www.bundestag.de/htdocs_e/visits/index.jsp

**Short summary:**

- There are no restrictions for non-german citizens.
- You can participate in a guided tour and you can even watch a debate from the tribune of the reichstag for ~1 hour. You need a reservation for that, but you can do this online (see the link above).
- You need a reservation too, if you want to go to the dome ("kuppel") and the roofgarden ("dachterrasse"), but this is included in some of the offers available I believe.
- You may also visit a congressman with a group of >10 visitors, but you will need an early reservation for this.